# Angry Professor Hackerrank

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am solving [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/angry-professor/problem?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen) problem on hackerrank. It seems to be a simple problem where I count all the value that are `<= 0` in the array and return whether the count equals to `k`, which is what I have implemented in my code. I pass the test case just fine but fail all other 11 hidden cases. What am I doing wrong?

```
function angryProfessor(k, a) {
  let count = 0;
  for (let num of a) {
    if (num <= 0) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  if (count === k) {
    return 'NO'
  } else {
    return 'YES'
  }
}
```

Comment: Consider stopping when `k` is reached.

Comment: What if `count` is greater than `k`?

Comment: Hint: If k is less than n your code will say class is cancelled even if every student is on time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question asks a minimum number of students, for e.g. if k=3 then if there are more than 3 students then also the class will happen.So change your if condition i.e. if (count === k) condition to this if (count >= k)